# How to restrict "--" using getopt in linux c?

Tags: c, getopt-long

I have to restrict when the user gives "--" as an option.
For example:

```
./test --
```

should thrown an error. 
For the sake of parsing I am using [getopt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html)

How to achieve this using getopt?

Comment: Can you please try to [add more text](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23738016/edit)? I find it very hard to understand your question.

Comment: The [`getopt`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) function doesn't support double-dashes for options at all. Or are you meaning the option terminator sequence? Please *edit your question* to clarify.

Comment: I will try hinting about getopt_long, but it might not be what the questioner wanted to know about.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes it does. `--` marks the end of option arguments, even if the next subsequent argument looks like it would be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getopt` is intended for implementing programs which conform to the [POSIX Utility Syntax Guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) where `--` has a special meaning of causing all subsequent arguments to be treated as non-options even if they have the form of options (e.g. `rm -- -f` to remove a file named `-f`). There's no explicit way to suppress this behavior. You could try checking whether `argv[optind-1]` is `"--"` after `getopt` finishes, but this would give false positives in cases where the `"--"` was the argument to an option that takes an argument (something like `-f --` where `-f` needs an argument) which you might need to work around.

If you really want argument handling that does not conform to the Utility Syntax Guidelines you might be better off rolling your own from scratch.